# Clear contents and formatting of an Excel cell with a single command

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

If you want to clear the contents of a cell or range in Microsoft Excel, you can use `.ClearContents`. If you also want to clear the formatting, you can use `.ClearFormats`.

```
Sheets("Test").Range("A1:C3").ClearContents
Sheets("Test").Range("A1:C3").ClearFormats
```

If you want to do both, you can use `.Delete`, but then the other cells in the spreadsheet shift to replace the deleted cells.

```
Sheets("Test").Range("A1:C3").Delete
```

How can you remove the contents *and* the formatting of a cell or range in VBA with a single command, without affecting the rest of the worksheet?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use the `.Clear` method.

```
Sheets("Test").Range("A1:C3").Clear
```

[MSDN documentation here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff820947.aspx)

Comment: I spent an embarrassingly long time looking for that solution, hopefully it will save someone else the trouble.

Comment: **Word of Caution**: `.Clear` API also removes the formula if any in the target cells. In that regard `ClearContents` is much safer.

Comment: @RBT I'm don't think that's the case, the [documentation for `.ClearContents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-clearcontents-method-excel) specifically mentions removing formulas.  The only further consideration I can think of before using `.Clear` is that it will also clear any notes you have left on that cell.

Comment: @MackM Please check the documentation that you've referred in your own post for `.Clear` method. Example section of the documentation page says that - `This example clears the formulas and formatting in cells A1:G37 on Sheet1.`

Comment: the documentation has been updated: `Range.Clear [...] clears formulas and values [...] but leaves the cell formatting and conditional formatting intact`

Comment: @martin.lindenlauf Where do you see that?  I see it in the documentation for [`.ClearContents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.ClearContents) but not for [`.Clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Clear)

Comment: @MackM you are right. I can't verify my statement - seems I went wrong. Sorry!