# search find matches and copy range of rows to another sheet

Tags: vba

Sheet(LIST2) has 8 columns.Column A of Sheet(LIST2) contains id numbers.same ID  number is repeated many times in many rows of column A.Column B to H contains other data.
In sheets(Sheet1) A1 we type an ID number which find matches in Sheets(LIST2) column A and copy each math row from A to H

I found a code to copy the entire rows but what I want is only rows A to H only

Sub SearchForString()

```
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer


On Error GoTo Err_Execute


'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = 3

Dim sheetTarget As String: sheetTarget = "sheet1"
Dim sheetToSearch As String: sheetToSearch = "LIST2"
Dim targetValue As String: targetValue = Sheets(sheetTarget).Range("A1").Value  'Value in sheet2!A1 to be searched in sheet1
Dim columnToSearch As String: columnToSearch = "A"
Dim iniRowToSearch As Integer: iniRowToSearch = 2
Dim LSearchRow As Long 'As far as it is not clear the number of rows you will be considering, better relying on the long type
Dim maxRowToSearch As Long: maxRowToSearch = 2000 'There are lots of rows, so better setting a max. limit

If (Not IsEmpty(targetValue)) Then
    For LSearchRow = iniRowToSearch To Sheets(sheetToSearch).Rows.Count

        'If value in the current row (in columnToSearch in sheetToSearch) equals targetValue, copy entire row to LCopyToRow in sheetTarget
        If Sheets(sheetToSearch).Range(columnToSearch & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = targetValue Then

            'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
            Sheets(sheetToSearch).Rows(LSearchRow).Copy

            'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
            Sheets(sheetTarget).Rows(LCopyToRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Sheets(sheetTarget).Rows(LCopyToRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
            'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
        End If

        If (LSearchRow >= maxRowToSearch) Then
            Exit For
        End If

    Next LSearchRow

    'Position on cell A3
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A3").Select


End If

Exit Sub
```

Err_Execute:

End Sub

I like to copy and paste each row from  column A to column H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the range you are copying , so instead copying the full row you should just copy the columns you want

Could you try with this lines?

```
Sheets(sheetToSearch).Range("a" & LSearchRow, "h" & LSearchRow).Copy
'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
Sheets(sheetTarget).Range("a" & LCopyToRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(sheetTarget).Range("a" & LCopyToRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
```

To avoid overwriting "A3" when changing "ID" , could you try replacing the beguinning of the "sub" by this?

```
Sub matchandcopy()

Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
Dim sheetTarget As String: sheetTarget = "sheet1"
Dim sheetToSearch As String: sheetToSearch = "LIST2"
Dim targetValue As String: targetValue = Sheets(sheetTarget).Range("A1").Value  'Value in sheet2!A1 to be searched in sheet1
Dim columnToSearch As String: columnToSearch = "A"
Dim iniRowToSearch As Integer: iniRowToSearch = 2
Dim LSearchRow As Long 'As far as it is not clear the number of rows you will be considering, better relying on the long type
Dim maxRowToSearch As Long: maxRowToSearch = 2000 'There are lots of rows, so better setting a max. limit


LCopyToRow = Sheets(sheetTarget).Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
If LCopyToRow > 100000 Then LCopyToRow = 3

If (Not IsEmpty(targetValue)) Then 'here goes the rest of the sub with no changes  ....
```

Comment: every time I change ID number  it is overwriting at A3.  Please change code to add so data may be added on sheet1 in the next row on the next row it is

Comment: Hi @George , did you check the code to avoid "id" issue?

Comment: IT IS WORKING GOOD

Comment: great! any problems just tell me , also would appreciate any positive vote ; )

Comment: please tell me how to undo everything on a sheet and bring back as if a new sheet.

Comment: Well , this looks like a completely different question , anyway I would try with `activesheet.range("a1:aa1000").clearcontents`

Comment: try activesheet.range("a1:aa1000").clear ,as suggested  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884818/clear-contents-and-formatting-of-an-excel-cell-with-a-single-command)

Comment: WORKING VERY GOOD

Comment: great! I am so happy now! imagine how happy would I be after an upvote or something! ; )